# Value from useRef React hook has initial value only

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to use a hook to store state. This hook exposes the reference to the value and a simple mutator function. I would like to have a different updater hook which uses said mutator. While in the updater the value is correct, if I have yet another hook the value is always the initial value. Here is an example which reproduces the issue.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

function useCounter() {
  const counter = useRef<number>(0);

  const increment = () => {
    counter.current++;
  };

  return [counter, increment] as const;
}

function useUpdate() {
  const [counter, increment] = useCounter();

  console.log("rendering update");

  return () => {
    increment();

    console.log(counter.current);
  };
}

function useLoop() {
  const update = useUpdate();
  const [counter] = useCounter();

  console.log("rendering loop");

  return () => {
    update();
    console.log(counter.current);
  };
}

export default function App() {
  const loop = useLoop();

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = window.setInterval(loop, 1000);

    return () => {
      window.clearInterval(id);
    };
  }, [loop]);

  return <div />;
}
```

Inside useUpdate the value of the counter is correct, but inside useLoop it is always 0. I'm using a ref because the hooks shouldn't need to be re-run when the counter changes and because it is an object, the function returned from loop should take it by reference and always have to most up-to-date value, but that isn't the case. 
My goal is to use a similiar pattern to write a simulation combined with p5js. This issue is not at all related to p5, so I simply mocked its update functionality.
I tried using useState, useCallback but nothing worked.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-chatterjee-eyd85?file=/src/App.tsx:0-822)

I'm new to hooks and this pattern might be completely wrong. I'd welcome tips about advanced decomposition with hooks.

Thank you!

EDIT:

The problem is that useCounter runs twice and creates two different, unrelated instances. Here is my proposed solution for state decomposition:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

function useCounter() {
  const counter = useRef<number>(0);

  const increment = () => {
    counter.current++;
  };

  return { counter, increment };
}

function useUpdate({ counter, increment }) {

  console.log("rendering update");

  return () => {
    increment();

    console.log(counter.current);
  };
}

function useLoop(state) {
  const update = useUpdate(state);

  console.log("rendering loop");

  return () => {
    update();
    console.log(state.counter.current);
  };
}

export default function App() {

  const state = useCounter();
  const loop = useLoop(state);

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = window.setInterval(loop, 1000);

    return () => {
      window.clearInterval(id);
    };
  }, [loop]);

  return <div />;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `useLoop` you instantiated a new version of `counter` which is different from the one you declared before.
To solve the issue you need return `counter` from `useUpdate` so:

```
function useUpdate() {
  const [counter, increment] = useCounter();

  console.log("rendering update");

  const incrementFunc = () => {
    increment();

    console.log(counter.current);
  };
  return [incrementFunc, counter]
}

function useLoop() {
  const [update, counter] = useUpdate();
  // const [counter] = useCounter(); this will be a new counter

  console.log("rendering loop");

  return () => {
    update();
    console.log(counter.current);
  };
}
```

Comment: The proposed solution isn't what I'm looking for, but it helped me understand the problem. To clarfiy, the problem is that useCounter runs twice, both in Update and Loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a scope issue. You initialize a new counter variable in useLoop which is independent from the one in useUpdate. You must return both the variable and its mutator function from the hook. I did the following changes to useUpdate and useLoop hooks, and it seems to be working as you expected.

```
function useUpdate() {
  const [counter, increment] = useCounter();

  console.log("rendering update");

  // return both counter and its mutator function
  return [counter, () => {
    increment();

    console.log(counter.current);
  }];
}

function useLoop() {
  // use counter variable exported from useUpdate hook
  const [counter, update] = useUpdate();

  console.log("rendering loop");

  return () => {
    update();
    console.log(counter.current);
  };
}
```

Not sure if this is helpful, I am also new to Hooks maybe someone with more experience can answer better.

Comment: Thank you, but this isn't really helpful because this pattern would get really messy with multiple hooks.